# highlight THREE.Line in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Since I can't make the `THREE.Line` width greater than 1, I was wondering whether there any alternatives to achieve similar visual effect??

I was considering drawing several lines positioned next to each other.
But as it would increase amount of vertices in all my lines, I'd 
leave that as last option.

The other option that came to my mind was using some kind of glowing effect. 
But I'm not sure how to do that on `THREE.Line`.

What's the best way to achieve a glowing effect for THREE.LINE?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r76/three.min.js"></script>

<header>
 <style>
  body canvas{
   width: 100%,
   height: 100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  }
 </style>
</header>

<body>
</body>

<script>
var renderer, camera, scene, controls;


function initRenderer(){
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 renderer.setClearColor(0x264d73, 1);
}

function initScene(){
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
}

function initCamera(){
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
 camera.position.set( 0, 50, 0 );
 camera.lookAt(scene.position);
 scene.add(camera);
}

function initLights(){
 var aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xD0D0D0, 0.5);
 scene.add(aLight);
}

////// Initializers ////////////////////////

function add_path(){
 path = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
  new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 10.600006103515625 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 10.600006103515625 )
 ]);

 path.closed = true;
   path.type = "catmullrom";
 path.tension = 0.1;
 
 var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff00f0,
    });
 var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var splinePoints = path.getPoints(20);
 for (var i = 0; i < splinePoints.length; i++) {
        geometry.vertices.push(splinePoints[i]);
    }
 var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    scene.add(line);
 camera.lookAt(line.position);
 camera.position.x += 7;
 camera.position.y -= 30;
 camera.position.z += 5;
}

///// Mouse events ////////

///// Main /////////
function main(){
 initRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 initScene();
 initCamera(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 initLights();
 add_path();
 animate();
}

function animate(){
 window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 render_all();
}

function render_all(){
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
</script>
```

Comment: What do you think about rendering lines to texture and widening them in another render pass?

Comment: well never tried that one, not sure if that would be the best option IMO, as I'd like to use this glowing effect for highlighting certain areas in a hexagonal grid.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue quite long, the cleanest and most optimal (in sense of GPU and code) solution I found to highlight a line at the end was to change its color.